# Geth syncing fast Ropsten too long delays between importing new segments

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, ropsten, fast-sync

i have a problem with my Geth Ropsten node.
Time between importing new segments of chain is too long.
For example logs from my docker container below

```
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|13:30:02.701] Imported new chain segme
nt               blocks=13  txs=71    mgas=20.888   elapsed=282.171ms mgasps=74.
026   number=4993408 hash=9a9f69?22074c cache=26.65mB                           
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|13:30:02.779] Imported new chain segme
nt               blocks=2   txs=7     mgas=2.734    elapsed=30.968ms  mgasps=88.
270   number=4993410 hash=fd6bd1?440791 cache=26.59mB                           
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|13:32:13.384] Regenerated local transa
ction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0                                      
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|14:32:13.383] Regenerated local transa
ction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0                                      
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|15:32:13.383] Regenerated local transa
ction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0                              geth-tes
tnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|16:00:20.934] Imported new chain segment      
         blocks=4   txs=513   mgas=19.923   elapsed=8.411s    mgasps=2.369    nu
mber=4910406 hash=74ea55?fbb40a age=2w6h10m   cache=27.72mB                     
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|16:00:28.995] Imported new chain segme
nt               blocks=17  txs=742   mgas=40.461   elapsed=8.061s    mgasps=5.0
19    number=4910423 hash=3cb406?abe2a6 age=2w6h6m    cache=30.14mB             
geth-testnet_1_6d184080c9e1 | INFO [02-11|16:00:37.659] Imported new chain segme
nt               blocks=29  txs=749   mgas=84.302   elapsed=8.663s    mgasps=9.7
```

2.5 hours between synchronization cycles. 
I suppose problem related to unstable connection to peers (they are default).
How can improve synchornization time for my node?

May be someone has list of stable peers or provide information where i can find it.
Or may be problem is not related to it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with Ropsten testnet, I fixed it by switching to rinkeby testnet and mainnet